# Optimization over probability distribution vs the realizations

Tags: probability, measure-theory, optimization, optimal-control

How can one transform an optimization problem where the decision variable is a probability distribution, i.e., something like $max_{P \in \mathcal{P}} \mathbb{E}_P[X]$ to an optimization problem over the realization of the randomness?

Comment: By the realization of the randomness do you mean that you have a sequence of $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ samples and you are trying to find a pdf that maximizes the expectation? Are you trying to find the best $P$ from a given set $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: @Arash exactly!

Comment: What is unclear to me is that how does the realization affect/alter the optimization. For instance, you might impose a constraint like “the expectation should not deviate from empirical mean more than something,” such and such. I am afraid the optimization problem as it is right now does not account for those realizations.